# How can I multiply my element created with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
                container = document.querySelector('.itemContainer');       

                for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
                    container.innerHTML += '<div class="item"></div>';
        

                    if((i % 5) == 0){ 
                        document.querySelectorAll('.item')[i].style.setProperty("--width", 4+"px");
                    }       

                    document.querySelectorAll('.item')[i].style.transform = "rotate(" + i * 6 + "deg)";     
                }
```

```css
                * {
                    margin       : 0;
                    padding:   : 0;
                    box-sizing : border-box;
                }

                body {
                    width                   : 100%;
                    height                  : 100vh;
                    display                 : flex;
                    justify-content : center;
                    align-items         : center;
                }

                .mainContainer {
                    position                 : relative;
                    width                    : 440px;
                    height                   : 200px;
                    display                  : flex;
                    justify-content  : center;
                    align-items          : center;
                    justify-content  : space-around;
                    border-radius    : 5px;
                    border                   : 1px solid black;
                    background-color : silver;
                }

                .itemContainer{
                    position                : relative;
                    width                   : 130px;
                    height                  : 130px;
                    display                 : flex;
                    justify-content : center;
                    align-items         : center;
                    border-radius   : 50%;
                }

                .item {
                    position                : absolute;
                    width                   :2px;
                    height                  :100%;
                    display                 : flex;
                    justify-content : center;
                }

                .item::before {
                    top              : 0px;
                    content      : '';
                    position     : absolute;
                    background : var(--background, black);
                    width        : var(--width, 2px);
                    height       : 10px;
                    text-align : center;
                }

                .item::after {
                    bottom       : 0px;
                    content      : '';
                    position   : absolute;
                    background : var(--background, black);
                    width        : var(--width, 2px);                       
                    height       : 10px;
                }
```

```html
            <div class="mainContainer">
                <div class="itemContainer">H</div>
                <div class="itemContainer">M</div>
                <div class="itemContainer">S</div>
            </div>
```

```
 I want to use my "Clock Dial" drawn with JS in different Divs.
```

Couldn't multiply it. I'm confused. Thanks for all efforts to help.

Each div will show the parts of a clock: Hour, Minute, Second.

Thanks for any efforts to help. Hope the code is clear enough.

I have pasted "lorem" text below to send my question? ! :)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eum enim optio ut quisquam? Iusto, iure veniam alias, ducimus reprehenderit laboriosam eum aut molestiae dolor esse saepe facilis dolore consequatur autem quaerat illum inventore quia sint libero nesciunt!

Comment: Please provide a least working example using snippet and js you currently have. State expected behavior and current behavior of your code. Ask what you're trying to do and what's not working. That will help understand the problem.

Comment: I'm new here and have some difficulties. To be able to send question ı added some dummy text as you can see. And finding snipped took a lot of time. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a function and reuse the code like this

Update HTML with:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div id="h" class="itemContainer">H</div>
  <div id="m" class="itemContainer">M</div>
  <div id="s" class="itemContainer">S</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function makeCircle(circle) {
  container = document.querySelector('#'+circle);

  for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="item '+circle+' "></div>';
    if((i % 5) == 0){ 
      document.querySelectorAll('.item.'+circle)[i].style.setProperty("--width", 4+"px");
    }       
    document.querySelectorAll('.item.'+circle)[i].style.transform = "rotate(" + i * 6 + "deg)";     
  }
}

makeCircle('h');
makeCircle('m');
makeCircle('s');
```

Comment: This is a good solution. So that I need 12 segment for "Hour" part,  added second. parameter to change degree value and it works well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yup, my pleasure. Would be good if you can upvote the answer :P